# Output not displaying when running C program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

Good morning, I have a program that should be displaying an array(matrix) in a specific order and then in it's regular order depicted under Matrix C. The changed order is displaying. I'm not well versed in C, I'm learning. My code is based on what I have to use. 
However, when trying to call and run the regular order nothing displays to the screen. I'm not getting any errors during compiling. When trying to create a pointer to point to the Matrix and it's values, I get an incompatible type error. I did try casting and got the same error. I'm not sure if the cast or pointer declaration were bad. They did match with the reading and examples I saw however. May someone please look at the code I'm posting and point me in the right direction as to why it's not displaying the second line of output? Please point me or tell me what to do right with explanation. I'm learning and I know by the time I post on here I'm doing something wrong. Telling me I'm wrong repeatedly does not help me. I know that much that's why I'm here asking for help. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 8

typedef struct _Matrix{
double element [N][N];
} Matrix;

struct zigzag {
    int row, col;
} ZigZag[N*N] = {
    {0,0},
    {0,1},{1,0},
    {2,0},{1,1},{0,2},
    {0,3},{1,2},{2,1},{3,0},
    {4,0},{3,1},{2,2},{1,3},{0,4},
    {0,5},{1,4},{2,3},{3,2},{4,1},{5,0},
    {6,0},{5,1},{4,2},{3,3},{2,4},{1,5},{0,6},
    {0,7},{1,6},{2,5},{3,4},{4,3},{5,2},{6,1},{7,0},
    {7,1},{6,2},{5,3},{4,4},{4,5},{2,6},{1,7},
    {2,7},{3,6},{4,5},{5,4},{6,3},{7,2},
    {7,3},{6,4},{5,5},{4,6},{3,7},
    {4,7},{5,6},{6,5},{7,4},
    {7,5},{6,6},{5,7},
    {6,7},{7,6},
    {7,7}
};

int data[N*N];

int* ZigZagOrdering(Matrix x) // fill data and return data
     {
        int i;


        for (int i=0; i < N*N; i++)
             {
                int row =  ZigZag[i].row;
                int col = ZigZag[i].col;
                printf("%g ", x.element[row][col]);
             }
                printf("\n");


       }

Matrix InverseZigZagOrdering(int *x)  // pass in data and return a matrix
 {
     int i; 
     Matrix C; 
        for (int i=0; i <N; i++)
            {
                printf ("%g ", *C.element[i]); 
            }
                 printf("\n");
 }//IZZ




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // special case that allows us to initialize this way
    Matrix C =    {10,  4, 2,  5, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                    3,  9, 1,  2, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                   -7, -5, 1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0,
                   -3, -5, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                   -2,  1, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0};



    ZigZagOrdering(C);

    Matrix InverseZigZagOrdering(int *C);


}//main
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and what line does it point to? You also have a function declaration instead of a function call inside the main function.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm getting no errors when it compiles. So I'm not sure what I should be looking for. And for the second one I thought I had a call? The ZigZag is working correctly, the InverseZigZag seems to do nothing...

Comment: Yes, the Inverse is a declaration, not a function call. As you can see from the other function call it’s completely different looking.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen when I do 
InverseZigZagOrdering (C); 
I get 
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘InverseZigZagOrdering’
    InverseZigZagOrdering(C);
                          ^
testingNew.c:48:8: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘Matrix {aka struct _Matrix}’
 Matrix InverseZigZagOrdering(int *x)  // pass in data and return a matrix
When I try InverseZigZagOrdering (&C); I get 
 warning: passing argument 1 of ‘InverseZigZagOrdering’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    InverseZigZagOrdering(&C)
output: 1.35808e-312 1 1 -1 0 0 0 0

Comment: That’s is correct. It expects to get a pointer to int, not a matrix.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen  Well I understand that portion, I don't understand how I should point it to that Matrix correctly however and pull those values. :( How would I do that? I tried casting and it didn't work either, so I'm not sure if I did it right. I do (type) variable, correct?

Comment: You can’t and clearly the code is not supposed to work that way. The Matrix doesn’t contain any ints so it can’t be used as such.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ok I'm clearly envisioning this wrong. I need the Matrix C to print out. However I also need the InverseZigZag ordering function to keep the int *x. So I'm not sure how I should be looking at this at the moment then. I thought I could cast the pointer and have it call the values. What should I look at doing?

Comment: So what should I be doing?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so what should I be doing? I have a function with a int pointer parameter, I'm supposed to call and it's supposed to be getting it's information from Matrix C. This is in the requirements for the program.. So as a beginner you would understand why this is causing me more than a bit of frustration especially when I get at most 4 hours of sleep at night because of work.